# Subadditivity of betti number of pairs of spaces

Tags: differential-topology, homological-algebra, morse-theory

This question stems from page 28 of the "Morse Inequalities" chapter of Milnor's Morse Theory.

Given a pair of topological spaces, $Y \subset X$ and any field $F$, define $R_\lambda(X,Y)$ to be the rank over $F$ of $H_\lambda(X,Y;F)$ (also called the $\lambda$th Betti number of the pair $(X,Y)$). According to Milnor, the Betti number is subadditive in the following sense. Given the triple of spaces $Z \subset Y \subset X$, then $R_\lambda(X,Z) \leq R_\lambda(X,Y) + R_\lambda(Y,Z)$.

Milnor says the subadditivity follows from the exact homology sequence for a triple:
$\begin{align*} \cdots \rightarrow H_\lambda(Y,Z) \rightarrow H_\lambda(X,Z) \rightarrow H_\lambda(X,Y) \rightarrow \cdots \end{align*}$
But I don't see how it follows. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the long exact sequence one obtains a short exact sequence
$$1 \to \underbrace{\text{image}\bigl( H_\lambda(Y,Z) \to H_\lambda(X,Z)\bigr)}_{K=\text{cokernel}\bigl(H_{\lambda+1}(X,Y) \to H_\lambda(Y,Z)\bigr)} \to H_\lambda(X,Z) \to \underbrace{\text{image}\bigl(H_\lambda(X,Z) \to H_\lambda(X,Y)\bigr)}_{Q=\text{kernel}\bigl(H_\lambda(X,Y) \to H_{\lambda-1}(Y,Z)\bigr)} \to 1
$$
and so $\text{rank}(H_\lambda(X,Z)) = \text{rank}(K) + \text{rank}(Q)$.

Since $K$ is a quotient of $H_\lambda(Y,Z)$ we have $\text{rank}(K) \le \text{rank}(H_\lambda(Y,Z))$.

And since $Q$ is a subgroup of $H_\lambda(X,Y)$ we have $\text{rank}(Q) \le \text{rank}(H_\lambda(X,Y))$.

Putting this together,
$$\text{rank}(H_\lambda(X,Z)) \le \text{rank}(H_\lambda(Y,Z)) + \text{rank}(H_\lambda(X,Y))
$$

Comment: At first glance I thought it is clear to me but after I encountered a similar problem today I'm a bit confused. Why is the short sequence exact? If $\begin{align*} \cdots \rightarrow H_\lambda(Y,Z) \xrightarrow{i} H_\lambda(X,Z) \xrightarrow{j} H_\lambda(X,Y) \rightarrow \cdots \end{align*}$ is the long exact sequence we started with and $1 \to K \xrightarrow{i} H_\lambda(X,Z) \xrightarrow{j} Q \to 1$ is the short sequence in your answer. Then all of $K=ker(i)$ is mapped to $0\in H_{\lambda}(X,Z)$ by $i$, so exactness means that the map $j$ has to be injective. Why is this true in general?

Comment: I can see now that I miswrote my answer. I've made corrections, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: The map between $K$ and $H_\lambda(X,Z)$ is the map $\tilde{i}$ induced by $i$ (in my notation), right? Then $ker(\tilde{i})=0$ since in $K$ we quotient out all elements in $ker(i)$. Furthermore $\tilde{i}(K)=i(H_\lambda(Y,Z))=ker(j)$ by the exactness in the LES. Also $j$ is surjective on its image. Is this right so far?

Comment: That's correct.